# Why const reference discards in implicit template instantiate?

Tags: c++, templates, const-reference

I write a class with template method and use it like below.

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    template<typename T> void DoSomething(uint32_t index, T arg);
};

template<>
void A::DoSomething(uint32_t index,const string &arg) {

}

void Run(A &a, const string &str) {
    a.DoSomething(0, str);
    a.DoSomething<const string &>(0, str);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    Run(a, "HelloWorld");
    return 0;
}
```

This code failed with linker error : undefined reference to `void A::DoSomething<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >(unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)

So compiler discards the const reference qualifiers.

Why this happens ? How can fix it ?

Comment: `T` is deduced to `string` in the first example. In general, a by-value parameter will never deduce to a reference. If you want that, the parameter should be `const T &`, not `T`.

Comment: OK, you are right but how to differentiate between call by value and call by const-reference ?

Comment: Why do you need this? Templates can't do that. At best you can differentiate const vs non-const and lvalues vs rvalues.

Comment: what is "It" that you want to get fixed? In your code you only need to add `{}` after declaration of the member template and "it" compiles, perhaps not what you want. What do you want?

Comment: I have two type of classes some classes are persist and other isn't,  And I need bind them to a SQL statement I have write two series of Bind methods to bind data in correct why so if function call by value function copy data until statement execution else doesn't do that.

Comment: Can you add some code for that? Please reason about a [mcve].

Comment: I write another sample it's something like this https://godbolt.org/z/j9cEMWYKE

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) As this question already has an answer you could open a new question to ask for your actual issue.

Comment: @MohsenTi If I understand this correctly, I would write two functions: `const T &` and `T &&`. The first one copies non-persistent objects, the second one `std::move`s them. For persistent objects, the first one remembers the address, and the other fails with an exceptions.

Comment: But the whole idea of persistent vs non-persistent objects looks error-prone to me, but without knowing more about what you do, I can't suggest a better design.

Comment: It happens because you didn't define `A::DoSomething(uint32_t, std::string&)` you only declared the template (specializing it before it is defined is "Ill-Formed, No diagnosis Required")

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that the second parameter `arg` in `DoSomething` expects an argument to be passed **by value**. This means that `T` is deduced to be `std::string` and hence the general version of the function template is selected. But since there is no definition for the general version, you get the mentioned linker error.

For example,

```
template<typename T>
//--------vvvvv----------->by value
void func(T arg)
{

}
int main()
{
      const std::string str = "name";
      func(str); //T is std::string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems the correct answer to this question is perfect forwarding mixed with type traits.

below code shows how PerfectForwardDoSomething method call correct method.

```
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class DataClass {
public:
    string content;
    bool isPersist;

    DataClass(string content, bool isPersist) : content(std::move(content)), isPersist(isPersist) {}
};

class A {
private:
    vector<DataClass> keepUntilDestroy;
public:
    template<typename T>
    void DoSomething(uint32_t index, T arg);

    template<typename T>
    void PerfectForwardDoSomething(uint32_t index, T &&arg) {
        if constexpr (is_reference_v<T>) {
            DoSomething<const typename decay<T>::type &>(index, std::forward<T>(arg));
        } else {
            DoSomething<T>(index, std::forward<T>(arg));
        }
    }
};

template<>
void A::DoSomething(uint32_t index, const DataClass &arg) {
}

template<>
void A::DoSomething(uint32_t index, DataClass arg) {
    keepUntilDestroy.push_back(arg);
}

void RunRef(A &a, const DataClass &data) {
    a.PerfectForwardDoSomething(0, data);
}

void RunVal(A &a, DataClass data) {
    a.PerfectForwardDoSomething(0, data);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    RunVal(a, {"HelloWorld", false});
    RunRef(a, {"HelloWorld2", true});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what's with `isPersist` flag? Ignore it?

Comment: Does the `DoSomething` by pass-by-value actually get used?  Mine is only using the `DoSomething` by pass-by-const-reference.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes it's not required any more because persistent content call by reference and non-persistent content call by value.

Comment: @Eljay, yes it's get call because of explicit instantiate in PerfectForwardDoSomething method.

Comment: @MohsenTi • the code does not do that on my machine.  I never hit the breakpoint in the one routine.